# Send value of my sim card in get

Tags: java, android, get

I would like to recover the values of my sim card to send it as a get or post to my app php I read several topic and I try a lot of things but I am novice in java. And I dont know how to send data taken from my java application to my web site.

```
String IMEINumber = manager.getDeviceId();
String SIMSerialNumber = manager.getSimSerialNumber();

BtnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idBtnStart);
varText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTxtView);
varText.setText(info);
```

I try this without succes:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://www.example.com/erm**?data=SIMSerialNumber**");
HttpURLConnection connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using below code snippet:** Code for Post request in java, sending request to specified URL.

```
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        JSONObject responseJsonObject = null;
        try {

            URL posturl = new URL("http://www.example.com/erm**?data=SIMSerialNumber**");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) posturl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "<type of your content>");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
```

postBody -- will contain your value to be posted.

```
            wr.write(postBody.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }

            rd.close();
```

Save your response in any format you want.I'm using Json format

```
            responseJsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit in your explanations ? I am interested in this, and don't understand what you are doing to fix OP's issue.

Comment: I've given the whole code of sending post request to your server/website.